# can an cross-domain iframe detect a browser's actual viewport dimensions?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, viewport, dimensions

I have an iframe loaded inside a parent page - the iframe and parent page are on different domains.

**Can my iframed site detect the actual browser dimensions?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the excellent postMessage plugin from Ben Alman

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

this allows for cross domain communication where you have control over both domains.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the web API `window.postMessage` method too. It safely enables cross origin communication.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer, is no. It cannot. Unless by some means the parent window can dynamically send data to the object inside the iframe...

However if the content inside the iframe was all made in %'s so that it would scale nicely (similar to a fluid web page layout), this could help?

What is it that you are directly trying to achive?

Comment: I'm using the fancybox jquery plugin - which places an overlay 'panel' directly in the middle of the screen - which is fine usually but as this site is being served in an iframe its too far down the page, I need the overlay to be modified relative to the browser dimensions...

Comment: I have control over the parent site also, how do you reccommend data is passed between the two sites - so that the height and width of the browser viewport can be grabbed by the child iframe dynamically?